# What is the role of pH in azo coupling reaction of diazonium with phenol and aniline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ph

Why is it so that azo coupling with phenol needs basic pH (9–10) and with aniline it needs acidic pH (4–5). How does pH participate in the mechanism? I have searched the internet for quite a while nowhere does it explain the actual ‘role’ of the pH. Any light on this matter would be helpful.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Deprotonation of the phenol and protonation of aniline result in species that easily react with a diazonium cation in the intended manner.

Let's have a look at the species involved. On the one hand, there is the **diazonium cation**:

[image: diazonium cation]

Deprotonation of phenol yields phenolate, for which a resonance structure with a negative charge in *para* position to the substituent can be written:

[image: phenolate]

We conclude: **Deprotonation of the phenol means activation**!

[image: phenolate reaction with diazonium cation]

In the case of aniline, the lone pair on the nitrogen atom is the preferred centre for the reaction with the diazonium cation:

[image: aniline reaction with diazonium]

This isn't what we want! Protonation of aniline avoids this side reaction.

We conclude: **Protonation of aniline means "masking" the wrong centre!**

Comment: In the case of phenol, Why lone pairs of oxygen are not the preferred center for reaction with diazonium cation??

Comment: If aniline is protonated, then won't the benzene ring be deactivated in aniline? NH3+ is supposed to be a strong deactivating group. This deactivation should then prevent azo coupling because azo coupling reactions need highly activated groups.

Comment: Klaus, could you add to your post to answer the comments? They're good questions, and making a new post for them seems unnecessary.

Comment: what is the role of Ph in the answer given?

Comment: @PranoyDe [orthocresol's answer here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/107355/24750) answers why HCl is being used to form the azobenzene.