# Does aniline react with diazonium ions at C or N?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, amines, regioselectivity

[image: Reaction of aniline with benzenediazonium cation]

In the azo coupling of aniline with benzenediazonium cation, I thought of two possible products **1** and **2** that could be formed. However, I can't work out which will be preferred. What would be the major product and why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a really interesting question and the answer is that the reaction of benzenediazonium chloride with aniline is a bit different to most of the reactions of benzenediazonium salts in that the initial product is compound **1**, diazoaminobenzene. It is possible to run the reaction to isolate diazoaminobenzene [prep here](http://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-diazoaminobenzene/).

These diazoaminobenzene compounds are unstable with respect to reversion to a diazonium salt + nucleophile, and so many references suggest that compound **2**, 4-aminoazobenzene, is directly produced. The procedure for the transformation of diazoaminobenzene **1** to 4-aminoazobenzene **2** is by heating to 50 °C with aniline ([prep here](http://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-4-aminoazobenzene/)).

Answer (score 18):

In general, for anilines reaction at nitrogen is kinetically faster than reaction at carbon. However, the C-substituted product is usually more stable than the N-substituted product, so can prevail under thermodynamic conditions.

As noted by Mayr *et al.* (the discussion below is taken from the same article):<sup>[1]</sup>

> Similar regioselectivities are found in azo coupling reactions. It has long been known that anilines, as well as *N*-alkyl anilines, initially form triazenes in coupling reactions with benzenediazonium salts (N coupling), whereas C coupling takes place with tertiary aromatic amines. [...] It was reported that the reversible attack at the nitrogen atom is generally 20–25 times faster than the attack at the carbon atom. The mechanism *(in the scheme below)* shows that even diazonium ions prefer N attack of kinetic control. In the absence of base, the formation of the triazene is reversible and one observes the azo compound as the only reaction product.

[image: Scheme for reaction of aniline with electrophiles at C and N]

The kinetic preference can be traced to several factors. Firstly, the charged intermediate **2a** resulting from *N*-attack is more stable than the intermediate **2b** resulting from *C*-attack. This can be explained by the fact that aromaticity is disrupted in **2b**.

Secondly, there is a greater intrinsic barrier to a reaction at carbon, due to the large reorganisation energy involved in *C*-attack. To a first approximation, this can be understood in terms of atomic positions and electron density distribution: in both of these aspects **2a** is closer to **1** than **2b** is.

Both of these factors combined make the formation of **2a** much faster than the formation of **2b** (for more information, see: [Marcus theory on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_theory)). Hence, under kinetic control, the triazene **3a** (E = PhN<sub>2</sub>) is formed from deprotonation of **2a**.

If **2a** cannot be deprotonated – this is the case if there is no base, or if the substrate is an *N*,*N*-dialkylaniline – the triazene **3a** cannot be formed, and so the azobenzene **3b** is the only product. Otherwise, it is necessary to use thermodynamic conditions to obtain the azobenzene **3b**, which is more stable than **3a**. This is consistent with the experimental procedures that Waylander has linked in his answer, where sodium acetate is used for the formation of the triazene **3a**, and the HCl salt of aniline (without any added base) is used for the formation of azobenzene **3b**.

*Reference*

1. Mayr, H.; Breugst, M.; Ofial, A. R. Farewell to the HSAB Treatment of Ambident Reactivity. *Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.* **2011,** *50* (29), 6470–6505. [DOI: 10.1002/anie.201007100](https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201007100).

Comment: Orthocresol Tertiary aromatic amines and primary aromatic amines are answered .How about secondary aromatic amines ?

Comment: “N-alkyl anilines” means the same thing as your “secondary aromatic amines”. Consider, e.g., N-methylaniline (= PhNHCH3).