# Role of pH in azo C-coupling reaction, continued

Tags: organic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, reaction-control

In the question, "[What is the role of pH in azo coupling reaction of diazonium with phenol and aniline?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/29251/what-is-the-role-of-ph-in-azo-coupling-reaction-of-diazonium-with-phenol-and-ani)" asked by @DhrubaBanerjee and answered by @Klaus-DieterWarzecha, I find several ends untied. I considered starting a bounty on the previous question, but since my question is looking for slightly more specificity than just looking at the whole picture, I decided to ask a separate question.

That post discusses why azo coupling of aniline is conducted in acidic medium. However, I am not convinced of a few things.

My query is twofold:

1. The $\ce{-^+NH3}$ group is inductively deactivating (as mentioned [here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/31650/69977)). That is a turn-off for attacks on electrophiles (like a diazonium cation). But **why is the protonation of aniline preferred?**

> In the case of aniline, the lone pair on the nitrogen atom is the preferred centre for the reaction with the diazonium cation:
>
> [image: Diazonium and aniline]
>
> This isn't what we want! Protonation of aniline avoids this side reaction.

I do agree with Klaus-Dieter Warzecha that an alkaline $\mathrm{pH}$ would lead to azo *N*-coupling, but if we were concerned about the electrophilic attack occurring from the nitrogen atom, in my opinion, it should have been acylated at $\ce{N}$, leaving no room for side reactions but also keeping the ring activated (although less than before). I believe the yield would be higher.

2. **If an equimolar mixture of aniline and phenol was added to a reaction vessel containing benzenediazonium chloride in acidic medium, would the major product be phenol's couple product or aniline's couple product?**

[image: Major product?]

[This Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azo_coupling#Examples_of_azo_N-coupling_reactions) article states that phenol's coupling is base-catalyzed. I assume it accelerates the reaction by assisting the formation of phenolate ion. Going by that, the aforementioned conditions will be *less* favorable for phenol's coupling.

But I find it hard to take in that a protonated aniline could couple faster than phenol. Phenol would still be capable of coupling (only unaccelerated), while aniline should have been weakened by the deactivation.

Hence I would choose phenol to form the major product. I wish to know if my reasoning is correct or not, and if not, an explanation.

I would greatly appreciate any constructive discussion/specific answers.

Comment: AFAIK in coupling of aniline first triazene is obtained, which is then rearranged to aminoazobenzene.

Comment: @Mithoron Could you give a reference?

Comment: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/9acc6efb7db031d11d18/EP0052511B1.pdf

Comment: re @Mithoron's comment on coupling of aniline, it's discussed in some detail at [Does aniline react with diazonium ions at C or N?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/107344/16683)